# How to use "with them"?

Tags: punctuation

Which of the following examples are more correct?

1. Concerns for global warming are rising **and with them** the urgency to cut carbon emissions.
2. Concerns for global warming are rising; **with them** the urgency to cut carbon emissions.

Comment: Neither seems correct - "concerns" is plural, so the second part should be "and with them".

Comment: #2 is not correct because we use a semicolon to join two independent sentences, but "with them the urgency to cut carbon emissions" is not really a stand-alone sentence.

Comment: Also, we would say "concerns *about*" here, not "for".  Because we have concern for the planet and its inhabitants, we have concerns about global warming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second clause is intended to share the same verb (are) as the first clause. This only really works if the two clauses are linked by **and** as in your first sentence. Here are some guidelines for [semi-colons](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html), and none of them really apply to this situation.

Comment: Thank you JavaLatte. I edited the question. having this edition is the first item correct?

Comment: Also the second clause cannot stand by itself as a sentence, as there is no verb (as you mentioned). You might include this in your answer, as it is a basic point when using semi-colons (joining independent clauses).

Comment: @user3169: joining independent sentences is only one of the possible usages of semi-colons: other usages do not require a complete sentence after the semi-colon.

Comment: @Anacharsis, the edit does not affect my answer: the same logic still applies. The first is still the correct version.

Comment: See 1. and 1. here: [Grammar and Punctuation: Using Semicolons - Writing Center - Univ Wisconsin-Madison](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html). Honestly I think this explains it better.